# How can I extend the environment tabs in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, solution-explorer

How do you extend Tabs in Visual Studio 2013?  It would be handy to extend the Tabs so that you can selectively track an item in Solution Explorer by right clicking on a tab.

By default, Visual Studio will track active items in Solution Explorer via the setting: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > Track Active Item in Solution Explorer.

Having that turned on makes Solution Explorer jump around, and is consequently confusing on large projects, so I turn it off.  But, what I'd like to be able to do, is **right click** on an open tab, and select a menu item to make Solution Explorer track and display that file's location in Solution Explorer.  Basically it would be on-demand selective file tracking.

I know hovering over the tab, you can see the file path and locate it that way.  What I would like is a quicker shortcut to displaying the file location in Solution Explorer.

If there is a plugin that already does this, please let me know and provide a link. Otherwise, I'd be interested in knowing how to do this myself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button on the Solution Explorer toolbar **Sync with Active Document** and the corresponding command **SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument** for keyboard binding.